# How to get back closed panes in QGIS 1.8?

Tags: qgis, osx

I was using the map composer in QGIS 1.8 in Mac OS X 10.6.8 today and closed a couple of the object attribute panes on the right side of the map composer. However, I can't find a way to get those panes back? Can someone tell me how to do it? It is probably pretty obvious but I also can't do this for panes I close in the main window, too....

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several solutions for retrieving accidentally 'hidden' Composer panels in QGIS 1.8, [outlined here (checkout last one)](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/6125).

Panels in the main QGIS window are accessible via the View->Panels submenu.

This issue has been [fixed in master branch](https://github.com/qgis/Quantum-GIS/commit/c928868916192da22ef168ade3cfa525b872f5ce). If you want to try the master branch, there are nightly builds available for 10.6.8 [here](http://qgis.dakotacarto.com).