# How can I access lost panels in print composer?

Tags: qgis

In QGIS, I no longer have access to the panels in the composition for printing window (layout, history, object properties). QGIS 1.8.0 on a Mac.

What I already tried :

- The right click on the toolbar didn't work, while it works anywere else.
- I uninstalled QGIS, deleted preferences files, installed QGIS again, and menus didn't come back.
- I copied the preferences files from a computer where these menus are on, to mine, and the menus didn't come back.

Thanks

Comment: @YBergeot Have you tried the solution outline in the accepted answer of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33756?