# QGIS for Mac: How to restore menu bar and tool bar in print composer

Tags: qgis

I managed to hide both the tool bar and the menu bar in my print composer (Mac version 1.8.0). To get the tool bar back I saw you need to click on the menu bar. What then when you also miss the menu bar?

[image]

Here what I see. I right-clicked everywhere. I can't get the the check-box has described [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/38862/how-to-reopen-hidden-panels-in-print-composer).

Comment: Happened to me before, also others

http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/38862/how-to-reopen-hidden-panels-in-print-composer

http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/40674/how-can-i-access-lost-panels-in-print-composer?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Right click on an empty part of the Print Composer menu bar. A small window should appear allowing you to check the boxes next to the items you want displayed.

Comment: Doesn't work. What do you mean by "empty part of the Print Composer menu bar". Is it where the print composer used to be?